# Is there a laser assembler that produces PointCloud2?

Tags: ros, laser-assembler, laser-pipeline, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using the [laser_assembler](http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_assembler#Parameters) package to assemble laser scans.
This implementation outputs pointCloud messages, and in parallel, [point_cloud_converter](http://www.ros.org/wiki/point_cloud_converter) has been deprecated for diamondback.

Is there any implementation of laser assembler that would already output pointCloud2 format?
Or is there anything planned to implement such a node?
Else, I can modify laser_assembler myself.

Thanks in advance

Raph

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9909/is-there-a-laser-assembler-that-produces-pointcloud2?/) by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1382 on 2011-05-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think anyone has worked on this yet.  If you wanted to make a node which does that it would be greatly appreciated.  To get it integrated, please just attach it as an enhancement ticket for the laser_assembler package.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-05-19**:
BTW, is there any clear tutorial on how to access/write the data of pointCloud2? I find it quite hard has data is an integer array and you need to deal with endianess and the size of whatever is carried inside. I found myself stuck on it quite often an prefer using the pcl pointClouds as they have helper functions to access/write inside them.

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-05-19**:
I hacked the node by changing the service to ouput PointCloud2 format, and by converting the original pointCloud to pointCloud2 using  sensor_msgs::convertPointCloudToPointCloud2. If this is fine with you, I can post it somewhere, else some more effort should be invested into dealing with pointCloud2 everywhere in the code.